# Unable to save UTF8 to CSV in Python

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, utf-8

I am trying to save some text in Vietnamese language (after performing some operations on it) to csv file. I am able to save the same text into MySQL with no errors but saving to csv gives some weird output.

```
import csv 

test = [('Trưởng phòng Marketing và Phát triển kinh doanh',), ('Nhân viên Nhân sự',), ('Nhân viên Hành chính',)]

with open('results.csv', 'a', newline = '', encoding = 'utf8') as csvfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)  
    csv_writer.writerows(test)
```

csv output

```
TrÆ°á»Ÿng phÃ²ng Marketing vÃ  PhÃ¡t triá»ƒn kinh doanh
NhÃ¢n viÃªn NhÃ¢n sá»±
NhÃ¢n viÃªn HÃ nh chÃ­nh
```

I have tried decoding and encoding but it still doesn't save properly. Is this possible to save UTF-8 text to csv properly or this is an issue with the csv itself?

Comment: How/where exactly are you looking at that output?

Comment: Also, Python 2 or 3? Is the source code saved as UTF-8?

Comment: Pretty sure it's Python 3, otherwise there wouldn't be an `encoding` parameter in `open()`.

Comment: @deceze It's Python 3.4 and the csv output is the output in csv file when you open the file.

Comment: "Open" how?! Most likely the app that's opening the file simply doesn't treat the file as UTF-8.

Comment: @deceze - The csv's encoding is UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing *is* UTF-8:

- `ư` is encoded as `0xC6 0xB0`.
- You're opening the CSV file using a different encoding; looks like [Windows-1252](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) where `0xC6 0xB0` is represented as `Æ°`).

How are you opening the CSV file?

Comment: OK I tried opening the csv file in Notepad+ and the text looks fine. It does look like an issue with the csv file itself although the csv file is showing the encoding as UTF-8. Thank you for verifying that the text is in UTF-8 because I have spent all day trying to fix this thinking it was a problem with my codes.